# How to control which dependecy module to install first in OpenERP?

Tags: odoo

I have a customized module that depends on the Product module, I already put Product in the depends section of **openerp**. However, when i tried to install my own module, Im having an error pertaining to a field that the Product module provides. Is there a way for me to control the module installation sequence wherein it installs first the product module before my own.

Doing a separate individual module(product and then my module) works but I want to do it with just one module installation.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately  you don't get complete control over modules loading early There is two things you can do to influence this:

1. Add the dependant module to the 'depends' attribute in the **openerp**.py of the relative module eg: 'depends': [ 'stock','sale'],
2. Module loading is affected alphabetically, so give your module a name starting with x or z, and this should help in it loading last.